# Usar Object.assign para un objecto javascript multiple nivel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6, redux

Bueno me encuentro haciendo una aplicación React-Readux, y tengo el siguiente Array de objetos que tiene mi store:

```
const authors = [
  {
    id: 'cory-house',
    firstName: 'Cory',
    lastName: 'House',
    address: {
      city: 'Caracas'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'scott-allen',
    firstName: 'Scott',
    lastName: 'Allen',
    address: {
      city: 'Caracas'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'dan-wahlin',
    firstName: 'Dan',
    lastName: 'Wahlin',
    address: {
      city: 'Caracas'
    }
  }
];
```

Cuando hago un update, en mi reductor, tengo lo siguiente:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function authorReducer(state = initialState.authors, action) {
  console.log('actions ', action);
  console.log('state ', state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_AUTHORS_SUCCESS:
      return action.authors;
    case types.CREATE_AUTHOR_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.author)
      ];
    case types.UPDATE_AUTHOR_SUCCESS:
      return [
          ...state.filter(author => author.id !== action.author.id),
          Object.assign({}, action.author)
        ];
    case types.DELETE_AUTHOR_SUCCESS:
      var existingAuthorIndex = state.findIndex(a => a.id == action.author.id);
      console.log('Index ', existingAuthorIndex);
      return [
        ...state.filter(author => author.id !== action.author.id)
      ]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

El Object.assign que tengo en el `UPDATE_AUTHOR_SUCCESS` solo hace un "copia" superficial, lo que quiere decir que solo copia un nivel de mi Objeto, entonces al tratar de modificar el campo address, me arroja el siguiente error:

> browser.js?9520:40 Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected
>   between dispatches, in the path `authors.0.address.city`. This may
>   cause incorrect behavior.

Todo el problema es por que debo hacer una copia profunda (Deep-copy) de este pero no se como hacerla.

He intentado hacerlo:

```
case types.UPDATE_USERS:
  console.log('My uaser ', action);
  return [
      ...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.user.id),
      Object.assign({},  action.user, action.user.address)
    ];
```

Pero igual me falla, ya que no es lo correcto.

**Actualización**

Por alguna razón en el componente donde gestiono mi update lo tenía así:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import AuthorForm from './AuthorForm';
import * as authorActions from '../../actions/authorActions';
import toastr from 'toastr';

export class AuthorManagePage extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.state={
      author: Object.assign({}, props.author),
      errors:{},
      saving: false
    };

    this.saveAuthor = this.saveAuthor.bind(this);
    this.updateAuthorState = this.updateAuthorState.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.author.id != nextProps.author.id) {
      // Necessary to populate form when existing course is loaded directly.
      var clone = Object.assign({}, nextProps.author)
      clone.address = Object.assign({}, nextProps.author.address);
      this.setState({authors: clone});
    }
  }

  updateAuthorState(event) {
    // const field = event.target.name;
    // let author = this.state.author;
    // author[field] = event.target.value;
    // return this.setState({author: author});

    const hasSubField = event.target.name.split('.');
    console.log(hasSubField)
    if (hasSubField.length > 1) {
      let author = this.state.author;
      author[hasSubField[0]][hasSubField[1]] = event.target.value;
      return this.setState({author:author});
    }
    // else if(hasSubField.length > 2){
    //     // let user = this.state.user;
    //     // user.address.geo.lat = event.target.value;
    //     // return this.setState({user:user});
    //     
    //     
    //     let user = Object.assign({}, this.state.user);
    //     user.address.geo.lat = event.target.value;
    //     return this.setState({user:user});
    // 
    // }
    else {
      const field = event.target.name;
      let author = this.state.user;
      author[field] = event.target.value;
      return this.setState({author:author });
    }
  }

  redirect() {
    this.setState({saving: false});
    toastr.success('Author saved');
    this.context.router.push('/authors');
  }

  saveAuthor(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({saving: true});
    var author = this.state.author;
    this.props.actions.saveAuthor(this.state.author).then(() => this.redirect())
    .catch(error => {
      toastr.error(error);
      this.setState({saving: false});
    }); 
  }

  render(){
      return(
        <AuthorForm 
          author={this.state.author}
          onSave={this.saveAuthor}
          errors={this.state.errors}
          saving={this.state.saving}
          onChange={this.updateAuthorState}
        />
      );
  }
}

function getAuthor(authors, authorId){
  const author = authors.filter(author => author.id === authorId);
  if(author.length) return author[0];
  return null;
}

AuthorManagePage.propTypes = {
  author: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

//Pull in the React Router context so router is available on this.context.router.
AuthorManagePage.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  let authorId = ownProps.params.id;

  let author = {id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', address: { city: ''}};

  if (authorId && state.authors.length > 0) {
      author = getAuthor(state.authors, authorId);
  }

  return {
    author: author
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(authorActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthorManagePage);
```

Y me di cuenta que en el constructor, en el `this.state` no se estaba copiando completo el objeto, solo lo cambié por esto:

```
this.state={
  author: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.author)),
  errors:{},
  saving: false
};
```

Y me funciona, pero lo que no entiendo es el por qué?

[El código completo esta acá](https://github.com/FreakDroid/reactCouseManagerEs6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente reemplaza por:

```
return state.map(author => author.id === action.author.id ? action.author : author);
```

Mapeamos el array de autores y por cada uno, comparamos si el id del autor actual pertenece al payload, en caso afirmativo, en lugar del author actual devuelves el payload (el editado).

**Actualización**

En realidad si estás haciendo un copiado correcto en el estado:

```js
const author = {
  id: 'cory-house',
  firstName: 'Cory',
  lastName: 'House',
  address: {
    city: 'Caracas'
  },
};

console.log(Object.assign({}, author)); // -> resultado esperado
```

Lo que haces en `componentDidMount` es innecesario; `Object.assign` **copia varios niveles de profundidad**; sin embargo, deberías tener cuidado si el objeto a clonar tiene referencias ya que **este método solo copia valores**.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.author.id != nextProps.author.id) {
    const author = Object.assign({}, nextProps.author);
    this.setState({author }); // fíjate que habías escrito 'authors'
  }
}
```

En el código anterior tenías un error tipográfico; al actualizar el estado lo hacías con la clave *authors*; de hecho, lo lógico sería que cuando recibieses un nuevo autor en el componente, **este nunca reemplace** al actual.

Otros problemas que veo es que en el código para actualizar y guardar, por ejemplo, **deberías clonar el autor del estado** en lugar de hacer una asignación, de lo contrario estarías guardando una *"referencia"* al objeto en cuestión:

```
const author = this.state.author; // mal
const autor = Object.assign({}, this.state.author); // bien
const autor = ...state.author; // es igual, usamos rest spread
```

La función `getAuthor` puede ser reducida a:

```
const getAuhtor = (authors, authorId) => authors.find(a => a.id === authorId);
```

---

#### Recomendaciones

Si usas Redux, minimiza el uso del estado del componente. En tu caso, **no debería haber un objeto author** en el estado del componente; en su lugar, deberías crear un objeto `newAuthor` en el store y actuar directamente sobre él; de modo que al guardar despaches una acción con la cual el reducer quedaría como:

```
case types.AUTHORS_SAVE_IN_PROCESS: {
  return {
    ...state,
    saving: payload,
  };
}
case types.AUTHORS_SAVE_SUCCESS: {
  const authors = ...state.authors;
  authors.push(payload);

  return {
    ...state,
    authors,
  };
}
case types.AUTHORS_SAVE_FAIL: {
  return {
    ...state,
    fail: true,
    message: payload,
  };
}
```

Trata de abstraerte del estado de formularios usando [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/).

Comment: La verdad no me ha funcionado, me sigue dando el mismo error. Dejame ver si puedo subir un ejemplo a https://codesandbox.io para que veas mejor que ocurre.

Comment: Me causa intriga ya que los reducers solo devuelven una **copia actualizada** del estado. Por ende, devolver el estado reemplazando un autor no debería significar ningún tipo de problema. Actualiza tu pregunta y añade tu componente por favor.

Comment: Ya identifique el problema. Pero quiero hacer un test para colocarla. Es una locura, ya que era otro componente accediendo al state.

Comment: Ya sospechaba algo; ten cuidado con despachar paralelamente a la misma porción del store. Como consejo, te recomiendo usar la librería [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose).

Comment: Listo hice un update, pero me podrías explicar un poco mas al respecto, ademas coloque el full code (Esta en github)

Comment: @Wilfredo Editado, la verdad no veo la fuente del problema ya que el clonado en el estado es correcto; lo que vi es un error tipográfico al recibir un nuevo autor por props. Revisa mi actualización.

Answer (score -1):

Yo cambiaría el `Object.assign({}, action.author)` por `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.author))`

Esto te realiza una copia en profundidad del objeto.

slds,

Comment: Estoy lo hice, pero lamentablemente no me sirve, considero que mi error de  mutación esta en otro lugar. Voy a actualizar la pregunta con todo el código del app.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.author))` es una operacion costosa que no deberia usarse, y menos cuando dependen actualizaciones de UI o se piensa ejecutar muchas veces, como puede suceder en una aplicacion react-redux.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el clonado es en profundidad, por lo que ha probado en los browsers más modernos, tienes razón, este método no es el más eficiente.  
Aquí se puede probar si gustan: http://jsben.ch/bWfk9 
Saludos !!